# Shuffle values to a new row two cells at a time

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

To explain it in the easiest way possible:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
```

... needs to look like:

```
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 |
```

I've tried using the `TRANSPOSE()` function, but it doesn't seem to work in this situation.

How can I accomplish this simple task?

Comment: Do you need this to be a formula?  If not you can manually do this with `Copy` -> `Paste Special` -> `Transpose`

Comment: I don't think this is a data transposition so much as simply shuffling the right two columns into a new row below the original.

Comment: @Jeeped I just noticed that also.  It is not a true transposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an unused cell to the right use this formula,

```
=OFFSET($A$1, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2), COLUMN(A:A)-1+MOD((ROW(1:1)-1), 2)*2)
```

Fill right one column and fill down as far as necessary. Your results should resemble the following.

[image: Shuffle columns down]

Comment: Simple and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You put excel-vba in your tags, so I'll post the vba code for you.  I don't know how to do it with simple cell formulas.  Hopefully it's configurable enough to get what you want, beyond the simple example you gave:

```
START_ROW = 1
START_COL = 1
STEP_COL = 2
OUTPUT_ROW = 3
OUTPUT_COL = 10

Row = START_ROW
Col = START_COL
Out_Row = OUTPUT_ROW
While Cells(Row, Col).Value <> ""
    While Cells(Row, Col).Value <> ""
        For step = 0 To STEP_COL - 1
            Cells(Out_Row, OUTPUT_COL + step).Value = Cells(Row, Col + step).Value
            Cells(Out_Row, OUTPUT_COL + step).Value = Cells(Row, Col + step).Value
        Next step
        Out_Row = Out_Row + 1
        Col = Col + STEP_COL
    Wend
    Col = START_COL
    Row = Row + 1
Wend
```